# Using regex to find keyword in http response

Tags: ruby, regex, html-parsing

I asked a similar question earlier for which Nokogiri was recommended as a solution. I've used Nokogiri and it certainly works fine.

But due to certain reasons, I must use regex to extract a keyword from a HTTP response body.

Format of the keyword is as follows:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD> <TITLE>TestExample [Date]</TITLE></HEAD>
</HTML>
```

Here, `Date` is a dynamic variable, and I need to extract '`TestExample [Date]`' from the HTTP response body. Also, `<title>` can be lower or upper case.

Assuming 'response' has the http response, I have tried doing the following:

```
>> response
=> "<HTML>\n<HEAD> <TITLE>TestExample [Date]</TITLE></HEAD>\n</HTML>"
```

Then make a regex to search:

```
>> regex
=> /<title>TestExample (.*?)<\/title>/mi
```

When I do a `response[regex]` there are no results. No results with `response.match(regex)` and `response.scan(regex)`.

How can I do this task *using regex*?

---

Update:

For this task, this regex works fine:

```
response.match(/<title>(.*)<\/title>/mi).captures.first
```

Comment: I guess it is a typo, update "/title<TestExample (.*?)<\/title>/mi" to "/title>TestExample (.*?)<\/title>/mi"

Comment: I'm lost. Why can't you use nokogiri to get the contents of `<title>`, then regex search the contents?

Comment: @tlewin Yes, that was a typo. Thanks for noticing. I've been staring at the screen for too long. :)

Comment: @JoeFrambach I know that's pretty straight forward. I have used Nokogiri in other tasks. But here I must use regex only. It's an ask from certain folks.

Comment: do you have a *real* reason?

Comment: Those "certain folks" shouldn't tell you how to write code then, because their method is wrong.

Comment: Guys I know you are correct. Just don't shoot the messenger. Their reasons are security related, but remember I am not an expert like you to have a debate over their call.

Comment: `security related`!? Just show them this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other people said, Regex is not the way to go. If you're really bound to using Regexes (not just being too lazy to refactor?), this should do the trick:

```
response.match(/<title>(.*)<\/title>/mi).captures.first
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It sure works. :) ... I am noobie but not too lazy. :) ... as I mentioned earlier, I have used Nokogiri for other tasks but for this one, I must use regex only. Could you please tell about captures.first?

Comment: Ok then, no offense i was just trying to find out ;-) I'm just curoius: Why can't you use Nokogiri?

Comment: `captures` gives you the capture groups, i.e. the parts of the regex enclosed in parentheses `(...)` as an array. `first` will give you the first element of the array.

Comment: I've seen HTML with duplicated and multiple `<title>` tags, which would cause this to behave badly, especially when the `<head>` block was repeated after the body.

Comment: @theTinMan I hear ya. Let me try to share some more info on this regex use. There is a web app running on a device. It's got a welcome page where user first lands in post log in. This url is pretty minimal in content & has certain standard keywords. The regex is to extract & match these keyword. It is not a frequently updated app, the target page has a pre-set content & most (dynamic) functionality lies on separate pages. Do you still see any issue with using regex?

Comment: @Sunshine the problem is not how complex your specific HTML is, regular expressions just aren't the right tool for this because in general **they cannot parse HTML**. Regular expressions can only parse regular languages and HTML is not such a language. [Here's a fun read about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to handle this IS using a parser. Nokogiri will handle every requirement you stated, without breaking because of case differences or a difference in date.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<HTML>
<HEAD> <TITLE>TestExample [Date]</TITLE></HEAD>
</HTML>
EOT
doc.at('title').text
=> "TestExample [Date]"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<HTML>
<HEAD> <TITLE>TestExample [1/1/2000]</TITLE></HEAD>
</HTML>
EOT
doc.at('title').text
=> "TestExample [1/1/2000]"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<HTML>
<HEAD> <TiTlE>TestExample [Jan. 1, 2000]</tItLe></HEAD>
</HTML>
EOT
doc.at('title').text
=> "TestExample [Jan. 1, 2000]"

doc.title
=> "TestExample [Jan. 1, 2000]"
```

Comment: just curious, can I locate the keyword if it is *anywhere* in the http response?

Comment: The keyword? You mean tag? If it's in the parsed HTML body, yes. More importantly, it won't be fooled if `"<title>"` is in text somewhere, unlike a regex which would have a very hard time telling.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this pattern too:

```
/(?<=<title>)[^<]++/i
```

`[^<]` means all characters but < (character class)
`[^<]+` means 1 or more characters from this class
`[^<]++` means 1 or more characters from this class, and be possessive

a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html%E2%80%8E) informs the regex engine that it doesn't need to backtrack, thus performances are better.

example:

```
response.match(/(?<=<title>)[^<]++/i)
```

the idea is to not use the dot and replace it by a character class that exclude `<`

Note that the result is the whole pattern, no need to use capture group here and no need to test what is coming after. I remove the m modifier *(that stand for DOTALL)* cause i don't use the dot.

I just control with a lookbehind that there's `<title>` before.

Comment: What is `[^<]++`? That's not part of Ruby's Regexp engine.

Comment: >> response.match(/(?<=<title>)[^<]++/i)
SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):3: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<=<title>)[^<]++/
 from (irb):3

Comment: @Sunshine: Lookbehind are only available for ruby 1.9

Comment: @theTinMan: The Regexp engine supports possessive quantifiers.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I searched the doc for `++` but, of course, they don't have an example, and the text describing it only shows a single `+`: `A quantifier followed by + matches possessively: once it has matched it does not backtrack. They behave like greedy quantifiers, but having matched they refuse to “give up” their match even if this jeopardises the overall match.`